response handling in Js/AJAX
I created a function to update data using AJAX. On xhr.onload, this.responseText is not displaying any value in the console log, and only the else part of the condition is executing, even though the update is happening. I tried to debug it using console.log, but it isn't showing any value.
<button type="button" onclick="upd_general(site_title.value,site_about.value)"class="btn custom-bg text-white">Submit</button>

  function upd_general(site_title_val, site_about_val) {
   let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhr.open("POST", "ajax/settings_crud.php", true);
   xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

   xhr.onload = function () {
    console.log('Response:', this.responseText.trim()); // Debugging line
    var myModal = document.getElementById('general-s');
    var modal = bootstrap.Modal.getInstance(myModal);
    modal.hide();

    if (this.responseText.trim() === '1') { // Trim to remove any extra whitespace
     js_alert('success', 'Changes Saved!');
     get_general();
    } else {
     js_alert('error', 'No Changes made!');
     get_general();
    }
   };

   xhr.send('site_title=' + encodeURIComponent(site_title_val) + '&site_about=' + encodeURIComponent(site_about_val) + '&upd_general');
  }


Below down is the code on settings_crud.php
if (isset($_POST['upd_general'])) {
 $frm_data = filteration($_POST);

 $q = "UPDATE `settings` SET `site_title`=? , `site_about`=? WHERE `sr_no`=?";
 $values = [$frm_data['site_title'], $frm_data['site_about'], 1];
 $res = update($q, $values, "ssi");
 return $res;
}

filteration function
function filteration($data)
{
 foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
  $data[$key] = trim($value);
  $data[$key] = stripcslashes($value);
  $data[$key] = htmlspecialchars($value);
  $data[$key] = strip_tags($value);
 }
 return $data;
}

and update function
function update($sql, $values, $datatypes)
{
 $con = $GLOBALS['con'];
 if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, $sql)) {
  mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, $datatypes,...$values);
  if (mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {
   $res = mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt);
   mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
   return $res;
  } else {
   mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
   die("Query cannot be executed - Update");
  }
 } else {
  die("Query cannot be prepared - Update");
 }
}


console.log(this.responseText.trim()) gives what back? I don't see anything in the PHP that would give back 1.

You should get rid of filteration(). That is an old function that attempted to fix all security issues in one call. It did not work. The htmlspecialchars would convert anything that strip_tags would have removed/stripped.

There's also no need to clean the data if you're using bind_param().

You need an echo statement in the PHP to produce output.

Did you check whether this is a JS problem or a PHP problem? Have a look at your network console: is the request sent out with the expected data?  Does the PHP code use that data properly? Does the response the server sends look like the response you would expect?

if($res){  echo "1"; } else{  echo "no response"; }
??

@MujtabaAhmed Is that in your actual code? That is not in the code the question is showing.

Thank you everyone for answering.
I have solved the error .


function upd_general(site_title_val, site_about_val) {
  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", "ajax/settings_crud.php", true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

  xhr.onload = function() {
    try {
      console.log('Raw Response:', this.responseText); // Log raw response for debugging
      let response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      console.log('Parsed Response:', response); // Log parsed response for debugging

      var myModal = document.getElementById('general-s');
      var modal = bootstrap.Modal.getInstance(myModal);
      modal.hide();

      if (response.status === 'success') {
        js_alert('success', 'Changes Saved!');
      } else {
        js_alert('error', 'No Changes made!');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.error('Error parsing response:', e);
      js_alert('error', 'An error occurred!');
    }
    get_general();
  };

  xhr.send('site_title=' + encodeURIComponent(site_title_val) + '&site_about=' + encodeURIComponent(site_about_val) + '&upd_general');
}
<?php
if (isset($_POST['upd_general'])) {
    $frm_data = filteration($_POST);

    $q = "UPDATE `settings` SET `site_title`=?, `site_about`=? WHERE `sr_no`=?";
    $values = [$frm_data['site_title'], $frm_data['site_about'], 1];
    $res = update($q, $values, "ssi");

    // Log the update result for debugging
    file_put_contents('debug_log.txt', "Update Result: " . ($res ? 'success' : 'error') . "\n", FILE_APPEND);

    echo json_encode(['status' => $res ? 'success' : 'error']);
    exit();
}
?>



